# Ошибка при попытке запушить коммит на Git

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Возникает такая ошибка при попытке запушить коммит в ветку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать? Не понимаю из за чего возникает

Comment: Чего вам непонятно во фразе "Integrate remote changes (`git pull ...') before pushing again?"

Comment: надо бы все дубликаты в одну кучу слить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=git+counterpart

Answer (score 0):

Перед вами кто-то другой сделал `push`, значит, ваш коммит бы отменил его изменения.

Вам нужно в первую очередь получить его изменения через `git pull`, и только затем сделать ваш `git push`.

Comment: А как их конкретно получить? Какие атрибуты нужно добавить к git pull

Comment: Никаких. Просто `git pull` (это то же самое как `git fetch origin HEAD` и затем `git merge HEAD `).

Comment: @OnlyWeb, `git pull --rebase ...` вам даст желаемое, но скорее всего вы просто только создали новый репозиторий на GH, а там по умолчанию есть начальный комит.